# Soft keyboard resize mobile web on show up

Tags: jquery, css, layout, android-softkeyboard

[Before keyboard show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGlAC.jpg)

[After keyboard show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsK8G.jpg)

I need the keyboard not to resize the layout at all, just to appear on top of the page and let the user to scroll up and down. Here is my code

```
<html>
<header>
<title>Test Page</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
html{line-height:1.15;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
</style>
</header>
<body>
<div style='float:left;width:100%;height:20%;background:red;'></div>
<div style='float:left;width:100%;height:60%;background:pink;'></div>
<div style='float:left;width:100%;height:20%;background:tan;'><input type='text' style='float:left;height:30%;width:50%;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

And here the answer

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  'use strict';

  var orientationChange = function () {
    var $element = $('html');
    $element.css('height', '100vh'); // Change this to your own original vh value.
    $element.css('height', $element.height() + 'px');
  };

  var s = screen;
  var o = s.orientation || s.msOrientation || s.mozOrientation;
  o.addEventListener('change', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      orientationChange();
    }, 250);
  }, false);
  orientationChange();
});
```